# Nanoframework ESP32 SPIFFS or LITTLEFS support with nanoff?

Tags: spiffs, nanoframework

is there a solution to format esp32 esp 32 flash memory with SPIFFS or LITTLEFS and upload files in this partition with nanoff .
I try to use the sample webserver to read local file in flash storage, but i cant find a way to upload my files in esp32

Thx

I tried to format the ESP32 partition with platformio and read back with nanoframework webserver project, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When flashing an ESP32 with .NET nanoFramework firmware there is already a partition for NVS that's using SPIFFs.

Currently the only way to read/write from that partition is using the System.IO.File API or Windows.Storage (not recomended for new code).

There have been more requests for this (or similar) feature. We're considering it and how to best implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. 
I will wait for this feature to port our esp32 software with NanoFramwork